# How can the default route be removed on cloudfoundry using the manifest.yml

Tags: manifest, cloud-foundry

I define a route for my cloudfoundry app in its manifest file:

```
---
  ...
  routes:
  - route: example.com
```

My route gets successfully created during 'cf push' but unfortunately the default route gets created as well, i.e. I have two routes and I want only the one I defined in my manifest.

Any ideas how to get rid of the default route?

I know it is possible to remove routes, but as 'cf push' is triggered via a jenkins pipeline in my case I'd like to define everything in advance in the configuration. I assume that the manifest file is the best place to do so.

Even better would be if I can move the definition of the route into a manifest-variables file, but I'm trying it in the manifest file directly at the moment to be sure that this is not the source of my issue as I don't have much experience with it yet.

Thanks and beste regards,
Yvonne

Comment: A couple thoughts. 1.) Start in a new and unique test space. Try pushing your app and see what happens? Maybe something is stuck around from past pushes. Alternatively, delete the test app & clean up all route resources associated with it and try again. 2.) Try `cf push` outside your pipeline. Maybe your pipeline is going something to trigger this. If you can include full `cf push` command, you full manifest and full output from running `cf push` when this happens it might help to understand what is going on as well. Oh, let me throw in a third. Update your `cf` binary to latest, if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work, I just tried this against Pivotal Web Services, for which CAPI is always kept pretty up to date (currently API version 2.142.0) and it worked just fine, only creating the route I specified. Which version of Cloud Foundry are you using? Also, I haven't checked if there is such a configuration but maybe your Cloud Foundry instance is configured to always create a route on the default shared domain.

Answer (score 0):

One of the other possibilities is to use the commands **unmap-route** and **map-route** to map and unmap the routes of a specific application.